# How can I delete an account?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I have 2 emails gmail and yahoo. I was trying to add yahoo to gmail. But I created a new account with yahoo. What I want is to delete yahoo and add to gmail.

Comment: Here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account. Generic questions that apply to any SE site are better asked at the "mothership", meta.SO. Or do as Zypher says, if you want to merge.

Comment: for those who voted to close this is a perfectly _valid_ support request that belongs on a child meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

I've merged the two accounts now, you can log in with either OpenID - google or yahoo - and they will log you into the original account.

**/EDIT**

Did you want to be able to use both logins? If so, log into the yahoo account and let me know the UserID and display name of that account, I can merge them for you.

the user id will be the number in the url: `/users/<userID>/<displayname>` so for me it looks like `/users/17/Zypher` where my userid is 17 and diplay name is Zypher

Sorry also make sure the realname, age and email fields match so I know you control both accounts.

[image: UserID]

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/510/user510 The main account will be http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/452/pichoscosama